# CsvHelper writing header from two types with mixed ordering

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am writing properties from two classes to a CSV using CsvHelper. I have maps for them both. The issue is I want the header/fields to be in the order of

```
filename, FooId, BarId, FooName, BarName
file.txt, f1, b1, myFoo, myBar
```

and it only shows up as

```
filename, FooId, FooName, BarId, BarName
file.txt, f1, myFoo, b1, myBar
```

Here is some relevant code

```
public class Foo {
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
}

public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo> {
    public FooMap() {
        Map(m => m.Filename).Index(0).Name("filename");
        Map(m => m.Id).Index(1).Name("FooId");
        Map(m => m.Name).Index(3).Name("FooName");
    }
}

public class Bar {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BarMap : ClassMap<Bar> {
    public BarMap() {
        Map(m => m.Id).Index(2).Name("BarId");
        Map(m => m.Name).Index(4).Name("BarName");
    }
}

public static void Main() {
    Foo foo1 = new("file.txt", "f1", "myFoo");
    Bar bar1 = new("b1", "myBar");
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("Path/to/my/csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<BarMap>();

        csv.WriteHeader<Foo>();
        csv.WriteHeader<Bar>();
        csv.NextRecord();

        while (csv.Read())
        {
             csv.WriteRecord(foo);
             csv.WriteRecord(bar);
             csv.NextRecord();
        }
}
```

The constructor for the class is basic. If you would like me to post it as well, I will! My main question is whether it's possible to mix the two classes *within the maps* as opposed to manually writing out each field.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post all of your relevant code

Comment: And you should always post what you really got and not something that looks somehow like it. It is very unusual to have any whitespace before or after the delimiter within a csv file. Please check if that is really what you got from your code

Comment: @SirRufo edited. I omitted the constructor to diminish the bloat. I will update it if you would like. Also, thank you for the whitespace tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine them into a `FooBar` class and then map the `FooBar` class.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<FooBar> 
    {
        new FooBar 
        {           
            Foo = new Foo { FileName = "file.txt", Id = "fi", Name = "myFoo"},
            Bar = new Bar { Id = "bi", Name = "myBar" }
        }
    };
    
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {  
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<FooBarMap>();
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }
}

public class FooBar
{
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class FooBarMap : ClassMap<FooBar>
{
    public FooBarMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Foo.FileName).Name("filename").Index(0);
        Map(x => x.Foo.Id).Name("FooId").Index(1);
        Map(x => x.Foo.Name).Name("FooName").Index(3);
        Map(x => x.Bar.Id).Name("BarId").Index(2);
        Map(x => x.Bar.Name).Name("BarName").Index(4);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```